# Keras "fit" input unclear

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I'm trying to feed images of dimension `(350x350x3)` as the Input shape and I want to train the network to output a `(1400x1400x3)` image (4x upscale).

My training dataset consists of 8 images `1400x1400x3` which I flip around and such to get a total of 32 images for validation.

Then, I scale those 32 images down to `350x350x3` to obtain the input images which will be cross-validated with their 32 other counterparts.

```
print(type(validateData))
print(validateData.shape)
print(type(validateData[0].shape))
print(validateData[0].shape)
```

returns

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(32,)
<class 'tuple'>
(1400, 1400, 3)
```

And, similarly:

```
print(type(trainingData))  # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
print(trainingData.shape)  # (32,)
print(type(trainingData[0].shape))  # <class 'tuple'>
print(trainingData[0].shape)  # (350, 350, 3)
```

So when I do

```
model.fit(trainingData,
          validateData,
          epochs=5,
          verbose=2,
          batch_size=4)  # 32 images-> 8 batches of 4
```

What exactly am I supposed to feed as the two first parameters of the `.fit` function?

As it is, I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 1)
```

Here is my [full code](https://pastebin.com/2pXr7gxE) if you want to look into it.

[Keras API](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit) isn't very explicit about the formatting of the data that should be fed:

```
fit
fit(x=None, y=None, batch_size=None, epochs=1, verbose=1, callbacks=None, validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None, shuffle=True, class_weight=None, sample_weight=None, initial_epoch=0, steps_per_epoch=None, validation_steps=None)
Trains the model for a given number of epochs (iterations on a dataset).

Arguments

x: Numpy array of training data (if the model has a single input), or list of Numpy arrays (if the model has multiple inputs). If input layers in the model are named, you can also pass a dictionary mapping input names to Numpy arrays.  x can be None (default) if feeding from framework-native tensors (e.g. TensorFlow data tensors).
y: Numpy array of target (label) data (if the model has a single output), or list of Numpy arrays (if the model has multiple outputs). If output layers in the model are named, you can also pass a dictionary mapping output names to Numpy arrays.  y can be None (default) if feeding from framework-native tensors (e.g. TensorFlow data tensors).
```

---

Here is the full code of [another implementation](https://pastebin.com/zn0LPrg7) that I've tried using. This time, I changed the parameters to be python lists of np_arrays (each image being the 3D np_array). I now get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 32 arrays: [array([[[0.6774938 , 0.64219969, 0.60690557],
        [0.67257049, 0.63743775, 0.60206295],
        [0.67203473, 0.6418085 , 0.60398018],
        ...,
        [0.55292714, 0.5253832 , 0.46217287],
  ...
```

It's hard to know if I'm closer or further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fit(x=None, y=None, batch_size=None, epochs=1, verbose=1, callbacks=None, validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None, shuffle=True, class_weight=None, sample_weight=None, initial_epoch=0, steps_per_epoch=None, validation_steps=None)
```

In the fit function x is your training data. Perhaps it is more appropriately called X_train or something similar rather than trainData. In this case if you have 32 training images of shape (350, 350, 3) they should be stacked in a four dimensional (32, 350, 350, 3) array. If you have an array of your images as objects like you seem to have you can reshape using the following code

```
X_train = np.array([x for x in trainingData])
```

Then y in the fit function is the values that you want your network to output for the corresponding input, usually a label and in this case the larger images. You call it validateData but it's more commonly called something closer to y_train. Validation data is data that is not used during training but only during evaluation of the model after every epoch. So shape y_train in the same way that X_train was shaped. Expected shape of y_train would be (32, 1400, 1400, 3).

Comment: `should be stacked in a four dimensional (32, 350, 350, 3) array. If you have an array of your images` : this is precisely where I'm getting lost. I do not understand what python data type I should be using as input (np_array, or list of each image as np_array, or list of each image as arrays, or array of images as np_array, or... etc.).

Comment: It should be a single four dimensional numpy array of shape (nr_of_images, image_height, image_width, color_channels). You seem to have a numpy array of 32 objects. I've edited another piece of code in if the reshape command doesn't work (did you try it?).

Comment: Also realized I had some typos in the code examples, sorry about that. Should be fixed now.

Comment: not working. Would you mind [joining the chat here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169987/dawgs-waffle-haus) so that we do not spam the comment section? :)

Comment: For clarification purposes, I would like to let the community know that sds solved my issue. My numpy array was created with 2 different sized images, and -then- I would separate it to separate these 2 classes of images. However, because of the way the array was created, the separation would leave an artifact of `numpy array containing numpy arrays` instead of being a single `numpy array`. The `X_train = np.array([x for x in trainingData])` line of code, applied after the split, worked out! He also solved my issue regarding the input format: one numpy array of size `(num_imgs x W x H x D)`.